# If I'm moving with almost speed of light but without any acceleration will I see any relativistic effects?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, observers, relative-motion

As the moving is relative there is no matter on which speed you are moving if there is no acceleration. We will fill it exactly the same as no moving (if other objects moves with the same speed).

So, if we moving with almost speed of light but without any acceleration (imagine some magical way to achieve that speed, we don't care about it right now) and other objects around us that we can see moves with the same speed of light, could we able to detect it? Will we see any relativistic effects?

Comment: If you know that motion is relative, then what do you mean by "moving with almost speed of light" here? Moving with almost the speed of light *relative to what*?

Comment: @ACuriousMind relative to something. It's doesn't matter

Comment: You are currently moving at almost the speed of light relative to something.  Do you notice any relativistic effects?

Comment: @WillO Do you mean galaxies from the outer side of particles horizon? So, if I don't accelerate, I will not have any time delation issues, right? Does it mean that my speed is much more than speed of light relative to something?

Comment: @WillO I guess, you can make an answer based on your comment

Answer (score 1):

You are already moving at close to the speed of light relative to passing muons, and you do see a relativistic effect, namely that the typical lifetime of those muons is much longer than that of muons created in a lab relative to which you are not moving, the difference in lifetime being in agreement with the time dilation predictions of special relativity.

I should point out that 'seeing' relativistic effects with the naked eye presents some difficulties. People often talk about spaceships being length contracted, but if you were to pass a 100m long spaceship at close to the speed of light, it would be 150km away from you in one direction, and then a millisecond later 150km past you in the other direction, so it would be far too fast for you to see it close-up. If you were to look at a larger object passing at near to relativistic speeds a long way away, the appearance of the object would be distorted by the Doppler effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are traveling near the speed of light (relative to the earth), then the distance to your destination will appear to get shorter. You might get to the nearest star (four light years away) in less than a year (of your time).

Answer (score 0):

If you had a very precise clock ( https://phys.org/news/2021-09-world-accurate-clock-earth-cosmos.html ) you should be able to detect some "relativistic effects", even at terrestrial relative velocities.